# Split string after found symbol @ or number in swift ios

Tags: swift, string, split

I want get value before symbol @ or number in swift. I have email which is `john@gmail.com`. I want get `john` only. Another example is `peter34@gmail.com`. I want get `peter` only.

Answer (score 4):

Use `components(separatedBy:)` passing it a `CharacterSet` composed of `@` and the digits, and then use `first` to get the first part of the symbol:

```
let emails = ["john@gmail.com", "peter34@gmail.com"]

for email in emails {
    if let name = email.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: ("@0123456789"))).first {
        print(name)
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> john
> peter
> ```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
let EMAIL= "peter34@gmail.com"
let EMAILARR= EMAIL.characters.split{$0 == "@"}.map(String.init)

EMAILARR[0] // to get peter34
EMAILARR[1] // to get gmail.com
```